# Upload Codeigniter project to Cpanel Subdomain

Tags: codeigniter, cpanel

I really-really need your help. I've done too many hours researching this problem but I can't find ideas in resolving this problem.

I have an existing website mywebsite.com and I have a system which is made with codeigniter.

Now I badly want to upload my system to cpanel so that it is now part of my website mywebsite.com as a sub-domain it would look like mydomain.mywebsite.com.

this is my config.php base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mydomain.mywebsite.com/';
```

and my index

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

my default route in routes.php is

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'users';
```

my my users controller (application/controller/users.php) is

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {
   function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //enabling CORS
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method == "OPTIONS") {
        die();
    }
}

function index() {
    $this->load->view('login');
}
?>
```

my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

But when I tried to access it, it says

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

I tried to use the browser console to see for errors but no error appearing.

I tried to look for logs in the cpanel server still.

All the files are uploaded at CPANEL including the .htaccess (whole codeigniter system/projec)

Is my base url correct? since it is part of subdomain.
And please suggest an applicable .htaccess for me.

I tried all the post in stackoverflow but none of them matches mine.
ANy idea will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is your CI versions? What is your default controller name ? Add controller codes? What is your default controller file name?

Comment: What is in .htaccess file? Check whether `mod_rewrite` is set on server?

Comment: I have updated the question sir.. All the necessary files are in the cpanel public_html folder (root folder)

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty the value of `$config['base_url']`. Codeigniter is smart enough to know your installation path. I dont know much of `.htaccess`, but this is what i always use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. You can try to change the permission of the subdomain folder to 755. You can change it by going to **file manager**, and then right-click at the root folder (where you put your .htaccess) and then click **"Change Permission"**. The settings are as follows:

[image]

It works here.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30337587)